# PL/SQL Why my function return NULL value instead of a value in 'HH24:MI:SS' format?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to code a PL/SQL function to receive by parameter a number in VARCHAR2 type and return a hour in format 'HH24:MI:SS'. eg: If I send by parameter '6', the function will return 06:00:00. The problem is the function returned NULL value but If I write the same process in a simple PL/SQL block it works fine. Do you have any idea?. Thanks :)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION format_hour_test (
    p_hour VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    v_hour_time TIMESTAMP;
    v_hour_char VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
    IF
        REGEXP_LIKE(p_hour, '(0-9)') THEN
            v_hour_time := TO_TIMESTAMP(p_hour, 'HH24');
    END IF;

    v_hour_char := TO_CHAR(v_hour_time, 'HH24:MI:SS');

    RETURN v_hour_char;

END format_hour_test;
/
SHOW ERRORS;
```

[image]

When I write a anonymus block with the same process this works fine.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE
    v_hour      VARCHAR2(20) := '6';
    v_hour_time TIMESTAMP := TO_TIMESTAMP(v_hour, 'HH24');
    v_result    VARCHAR2(20) := TO_CHAR(v_hour_time, 'HH24:MI:SS');
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_result);
END;
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't use images when you can just use (formatted) text.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I pasted images just for show the result.

Comment: Basic debugging would have shown that the `if` condition was not being met, which would have narrowed it down to a regex question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the wrong type of brackets in your regular expression; it should be:

```
IF REGEXP_LIKE(p_hour, '[0-9]') THEN
```

You used grouping parentheses, insteaf of matching/class brackets. You would get a match if you passed in the string `'0-9'`, which wouldn't then be converted to a date/time.

[Read more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_posix001.htm#SQLRF55540).

Comment: Well, I don't know why some guy had voted my question negative. I think this page is for make question about programming... Thanks Alex, I should to refresh Regular Expressions and continue coding. Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Your anonymous block is **not** the same process. In the anonymous block you do not have `if regexp_like...` In regular expressions, parens group, so you are looking for the string `0-9`. So `v_hour_time` is not being set in the procedure.

I think you are looking for `[0-9]`, which is match one of the characters in the range. Alternatively, `[[:digit:]]` https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/ap_posix001.htm#i690819

Answer (score 0):

Your `v_hour_time` is never initialized, because of your REGEXP_LIKE conditional:

```
select (case when REGEXP_LIKE('6', '(0-9)') then 'true' else 'false' end)  as res from dual;
```

returns:

```
RES
-----
false
```